# What's wrong with my proof of the moment of inertia of a hollow sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

My method involves dividing the sphere into rods each with length $dx$ and width $dy$.

Then, the moment of a inertia for a rod about an axis passing through its end is $1/3 ml²$,
 so the moment of inertia of a sphere is going to be:
$$\int \frac{ 1}{3} mx² dy$$

Using the Pythagorean therom , $ x²+y²=r²$ we can say that the moment of inertia will be:

$$ \int\frac{1}{3}m  (r²-y²)dy)$$

When I do the rest of the math, I get $2/3 mr³$.

But, the real formula is $2/3 mr²$.

I'm confused. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried instead of a rod, you use thin slice of ring. It would be easier as the shape would be closer to a hollow sphere

Comment: Are you using 's' as integral sign?

Comment: There are many things wrong as  @CRDrost says, but I'd like to point out that your very first expression is wrong.   That is not an expression for moment of inertia; note that the dimensions are not correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong here; the chief one is that that's the moment of inertia of a rod *about one of its ends,* i.e. a point on the rod, whereas you're considering the moment of the spherical shell *about its center*, a point not on the spherical shell. So this will never be a valid derivation.

Instead for this sort of problem one would typically use the spherical coordinates $0\lt \theta \lt 2\pi$ going around the sphere and $0\lt \phi \lt \pi$ coming down from the pole of the sphere. A change in $d\phi$ corresponds to a real distance $r~d\phi$ while a change in $d\theta$ corresponds to the somewhat smaller distance $r~\sin\phi~d\theta$ as the circles of constant latitude get smaller towards the poles, having radius $r\sin\phi$, but the circles of constant longitude have fixed size. Taking this polar axis as the axis of rotation, and introducing an area mass density $dm = \sigma ~r\sin\phi~ d\theta~r~d\phi$, one straightforwardly has:$$M = \oint dm = 4\pi~r^2\sigma$$
but for the moment of inertia about the axis, $$I = \oint dm~\ell^2 =\sigma~\int_0^\pi r~d\phi \int_0^{2\pi} r\sin\phi~d\theta~r^2\sin^2\phi = 2\pi\sigma r^4\int_0^{\pi}d\phi~\sin^3\phi.$$The prefactor can be rewritten as $M r^2/2$ while the integral can be evaluated to $4/3$ giving the usual textbook result.